# Need help to create html page with css div ul li list to make it rotational

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am posting html content of my test page which I want to design like few of the web pages I have seen on different web sites. I want to create div with ul li list to make it rotational, at a time only three div should be displayed and remaining will be hidden. Hidden div should be visible only if I click on left or right rotation link

For example...

New product list on this site. www.mysmarttrip.in/index.php

Featured deal list on this site. www.freekaamaal.com

I tried a lot to make it like that but my knowledge of CSS and Javascript is limited. I need help form someone to make my page working like the site I posted above.

Thanks in advance... please help me

My HTML page:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <style type="text/css">
   .product_head {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 703px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid rgb(141, 196, 120);
    font-family: verdana,geneva,Arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
        background-color: #27638C;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 105%;
}
.product_page_box {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 204px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 2px 10px 5px 2px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid rgb(141, 196, 120);
    font-family: verdana,geneva,Arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.product_head .product_page_box ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.product_container_head {
    width: 204px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: rgb(234, 248, 228);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
.product_container_head a {
        color: #27638C;
        text-transform: uppercase;
}
.product_details {
        width: 172;
        height: 25px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 10px 10px 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(141, 196, 120);
        cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="product_head">
    <p> main title </p>
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="product_page_box">
                <div class="product_container_head">
                    aa title </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    aa 1 </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    aa 2 </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    aa 3 </div>
             </div>
        </li>
            <li>
            <div class="product_page_box">
                <div class="product_container_head">
                    bb title </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    bb 1 </div>
                                <div class="product_details">
                    bb 2 </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    bb 3 </div>
            </div>
        </li>
                <li>
            <div class="product_page_box">
                <div class="product_container_head">
                    cc title </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    cc 1 </div>
                                <div class="product_details">
                    cc 2 </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    cc 3 </div>
            </div>
        </li>
                <li>
            <div class="product_page_box">
                <div class="product_container_head">
                    dd title </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    dd 1 </div>
                                <div class="product_details">
                    dd 2 </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    dd 3 </div>
            </div>
        </li>
                <li>
            <div class="product_page_box">
                <div class="product_container_head">
                    ee title </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    ee 1 </div>
                                <div class="product_details">
                    ee 2 </div>
                <div class="product_details">
                    ee 3 </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did your HTML go through a meat grinder?!? What happened to all the `<`?

Comment: @NobleUplift +1  ^_^ Meet grinder, hahaha!

Comment: I removed it as editor was not allowing me to post html code

Answer (score 0):

use some `jQuery` plugin for example http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider or http://wowslider.com/